# PHP send data to modal without JS

Tags: php, html, data-binding, modal-dialog

I'm learning `PHP` and if I use java script I'll get a 0; hence the restriction.

So I need to pass a unique `$row["userName"]` from anchor tag to `modal`.

```
// I can use my $row["userName"] here to give each profile, an edit button unique to them.
echo    '<span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adminEdit" onclick="" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit user
                                        </a>
                                    </span>';
```

And I need that `$row[userName]` displayed here in the username `input`:

```
echo '<div id="adminEdit" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <form role="form" method="post" action="profiles.php?from=pictureUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Admin editor</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Username</label>
                                <input class="form-control disabled" disabled value="   ---  RIGHT HERE ---">
                            </div>

// More stuff below omited for sizing reasons.
```

Currently I'm looking into taking my `modal` OUT of `echo`; but then I stll have no idea how to pass the `$row[]` from  tag to the modal

Any ideas, would be appreciated as I'm  all out myself. ~Thanks :)

Comment: so you don't want to use javascript? Or you can?

Comment: No JS allowed is allowed on this code

Comment: ok so PHP only. You can do this but it will refresh the page, why are you using a modal? Because if you want PHP only then the page needs to be reloaded every time you click edit.